# How to check security of PDF file from excel?

Tags: security, excel, pdf, acrobat, vba

Using *Acrobat.tlb* reference I am trying to check, if PDF file is secured / has any restrictions set.
I checked Acrobat JavaScript Scripting Reference, but I am doing something wrong:

```
Sub CheckPDFsecurity()
Dim oPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Dim oPapp As Acrobat.AcroApp
Dim oJso As Object
Dim oSec As Object
Dim arrPolicies As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set oPapp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
oPapp.MenuItemExecute ("COMP:AddBack")
Set oPDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
oPDDoc.Open ("D:\test\test2.pdf")
Set oJso = oPDDoc.GetJSObject
Set oSec = oJso.security
arrPolicies = oJso.getLegalWarnings(True)

For i = 0 To UBound(arrPolicies)
     MsgBox (arrPolicies(i))
Next i

oPDDoc.Close
Set oPDDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Please would be someone so kind and help me with correct way of checking PDF file security setting.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the way. Maybee it is not the best one, but at least it is working and it gives information, if the PDF is secured.

```
Sub CheckPDFsecurity()

On Error GoTo NoSecurity
Dim oPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Dim oPapp As Acrobat.AcroApp
Dim oJso As Object
Dim oSec As Object
Dim arrPolicies As String

Set oPapp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set oPDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
oPDDoc.Open ("D:\test\test1.pdf")
Set oJso = oPDDoc.GetJSObject
Set oSec = oJso.app.openDoc(cPath:="D:\test\test1.pdf", bHidden:=True)
If oSec.securityHandler = vbNullString Then
NoSecurity:
    arrPolicies = "No Security"
Else
    arrPolicies = oSec.securityHandler
End If
MsgBox (arrPolicies)
oSec.CloseDoc
oPDDoc.Close
Set oPDDoc = Nothing
oPapp.Exit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ShowPDFSecurity()
Dim AcroApp         As Acrobat.CAcroApp
Dim PDFFinal        As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
Dim jsoF            As Object
Dim oSec            As Object
Dim arrPolicies As Variant

Set PDFFinal = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
PDFFinal.Open (FileLocation)
Set jso = PDFFinal.GetJSObject
Set oSec = jso.Security
arrPolicies = oSec.getSecurityPolicies()
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrPolicies)
        Debug.Print arrPolicies(i).Name
    Next
PDFFinal.Close
Set PDFFinal = Nothing
Set AcroApp = Nothing
AcroApp.Exit
End Sub
```